# Запретить обновление Timestamp при апдейте строки в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, timestamp

Здравствуйте. Всю суть вопроса я изложил в заголовке. Обновляется у меня поле просмотров при каждом обновлении страницы с новостью. Привожу код:

```
$count = $news->views;
$count++;

$data = array('views' => $count, 'date' => $news->date);

ORM::factory('News', $news->id)
     ->values($data)
     ->save();
```

При обновлении поля просмотров я изначально только это поле изменял, и поле с датой тоже менялось. Потом я решил попробовать заменять дату на ту, которая была изначально в этом поле, но всё равно не работает.

Comment: `timestamp` - это штапм. Печать. Оттиск. Это метка времени. Если надо менять - используйте `data` `time` `datatime`

Comment: @DNS Ладно, спасибо...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE
    `news`
MODIFY COLUMN
    `date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```